# Placing code and variables into a specific RAM section defined in the linker

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, microcontroller, ram

Thanks for taking a look.

When compiling my C project the linker generates a file where I can define the RAM sections I want to have, like this:

```
-ra RAMCHECK=0x00028000/0x000296FF

-ra D_RAM=0x0002a000/0x0002D6FF

-ra IDLE_TSK=0x0002D700/0x0002DFFF

-ra NORMAL_TSK=0x0002E000/0x0002EFFF

-ra HIGH_TSK=0x0002F000/0x0002FFFF
```

My question is the following:

How can I define a code section and variables into a specific place of the RAM?

Answer (score 0):

That's how it's done in `gcc`:

```
int data[100] __attribute__((section ("D_RAM"))) = {0}; /* should be initialized */
void myfunc(void) __attribute__((section ("HIGH_TSK"))) { ... }
```

Your compiler (what's its name?) probably has its own C extension, working along the same lines.

Comment: SOFTUNE Workbench V60L08. Where can I check that?